# how can I resolve this Logcat error

Tags: android

```
06-12 04:16:20.100 12243-12243/jaffri.sszj.dpcl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jaffri.sszj.dpcl, PID: 12243
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jaffri.sszj.dpcl/jaffri.sszj.dpcl.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at jaffri.sszj.dpcl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jaffri.sszj.dpcl-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/jaffri.sszj.dpcl/code_cache/secondary-dexes/jaffri.sszj.dpcl-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/jaffri.sszj.dpcl-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at jaffri.sszj.dpcl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-12 04:16:23.353 12243-12250/jaffri.sszj.dpcl I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 11
    Total arena pages for JIT: 12
    Total arena pages for JIT: 13
    Total arena pages for JIT: 14
```

Comment: can you post your code so we can see what the problem is?

Comment: We need to see how you are inflating your RecycleListView in order to give you a proper help

Comment: Please post the layout file you are loading at `MainActivity.java` line 28 (and any other layouts that it includes). Also post the dependencies in your module's `build.gradle` file.